# Mongoose model.find() returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have set up a database in MongoDB called **entertainment** with a collection called **medias**. This collection has JSON data within it.

When I make a call to the DB using Postman: `http://localhost:8000/data` I get an empty array returned.

Here is my entire code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

const uri = `mongodb+srv://tyrellc:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@entertainmentapp.jtcf92n.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

async function connect() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

connect();

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Express Server Started port:8000");
});

const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  thumbnail: {
    trending: {
      small: { type: String, required: true },
      large: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    regular: {
      small: { type: String, required: true },
      medium: { type: String, required: true },
      large: { type: String, required: true },
    },
  },
  year: { type: Number, required: true },
  category: { type: String, required: true },
  rating: { type: String, required: true },
  isBookmarked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isTrending: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});

const Collection = mongoose.model("Collection", collectionSchema, "medias");

app.get("/data", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Collection.find();
  res.json(data);
});
```

When running the app, I get both console logs: `Express Server Started port:8000` and `Connected to MongoDB` .

This is what my JSON data looks like in MongoDB:

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"63c733940231fb2f67b5344e"},"title":"Beyond Earth","thumbnail":{"trending":{"small":"./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/trending/small.jpg","large":"./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/trending/large.jpg"},"regular":{"small":"./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/small.jpg","medium":"./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/medium.jpg","large":"./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/large.jpg"}},"year":{"$numberInt":"2019"},"category":"Movie","rating":"PG","isBookmarked":false,"isTrending":true}
```

I have looked into pluralization and have tried:

`const Collection = mongoose.model("Collection", collectionSchema, "medias");`

`const Collection = mongoose.model("Collection", collectionSchema, "media");`

`const Collection = mongoose.model("media", collectionSchema);`

`const Collection = mongoose.model("medias", collectionSchema);`

Nothing seems to do the trick. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

MongoDB Atlas Database:
[image: MongoDB Atlas Database]

Comment: Since you're not specifying database name in your code, try including it in the connection URI: `mongodb+srv://tyrellc:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@entertainmentapp.jtcf92n.mongodb.net/entertainment?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Great, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify which database to use. You can either do this in your connection string, like this:

```js
const uri = `mongodb+srv://tyrellc:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@entertainmentapp.jtcf92n.mongodb.net/entertainment?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```

Or if you prefer, you can pass it as an option to `mongoose.connect()`, like this:

```js
await mongoose.connect(uri, { dbName: 'entertainment' });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find), `find()` method accepts parameters: filter type object required, and optional parameters.

If you want to retrieve all documents from the model you should pass an empty object `{}` as a filter.

```
app.get("/data", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Collection.find({});
  res.json(data);
});
```